# Spring ConversionService adding Converters

Tags: java, spring, type-conversion

I searched for the below problem, but couldn't find an answer.

I want to use spring's conversion service by writing my custom converter that implements **org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter**.

Then i add my custom converter as below:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean id="StringToLoggerConverter" class="com.citi.spring.converter.LoggerConverter" />
       </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

When doing the above my application initialization fails, because i am overriding bean conversionService and registering only my custom converter.

How can i not override the conversionService and only add my custom converter to the list of converters, at the same time keeping the existing ones?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While experimenting with different ways and even following spring source code in some i came across with an interesting thing.

The only way i found to use conversionService without overriding the existing converters with my custom ones was either to extend or re-implement the conversionService calling the super class's afterPropertiesSet() method to register the default converters and then add the custom ones.

But even if i was using that way, at runtime i was getting an exception that no converter was found for my specific types (e.g. from String to Logger).

That triggered my interest and i followed spring source code to find out why and i realized that spring was trying to find a custom converter registered with PropertyEditor. I am not sure why this is happening. I have to add here that my application is not using spring mvc and conversionService might somehow need to be registered and i didn't do it.

Finally, i solved the issue with registering a custom converter using Property editor. This documentation can be viewed as reference:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

I would be very interested in knowing why Spring was not finding my registered custom converters in the conversionService's registry (or at least why spring was not looking at that registry to find the custom converters). Was i missing any configuration?

Comment: Care to describe how to "registering a custom converter using Property editor" ?

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who stumbles on this now via a google search or similar 2+ years after the question was originally posted, adding converters has been made much easier through Java Config: `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` provides the `addFormatters(FormatterRegistry)` method that can be used to specify additional custom converters.

Comment: Look into `extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)` method in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to add your converter on top of default converters.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add it dinamically using addConverter method on your DefaultConversionService-ish class:

```
DefaultConversionService cs = new <YourClassThatInheritsFromDefaultConversionService or DefaultConversionService>();

cs.addConverter(new MyConverter());
```

Answer (score 2):

With spring > 4 it is no more necessary to implement an own derivation of the ConversionService. Initialize it in a @Configuration annotated class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class ConversionServiceProvider
{
    @Autowired
    private MyConverterImpl myConverter;

    @Bean
    public ConversionService getConversionService()
    {
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        bean.setConverters( getConverters() );
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        ConversionService object = bean.getObject();
        return object;
    }

    private Set<Converter<?, ?>> getConverters()
    {
        Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new HashSet<Converter<?, ?>>();

        converters.add( myConverter );
        // add here more custom converters, either as spring bean references or directly instantiated

        return converters;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could inject all objects of a certain type, `Converter` in this case, with Spring: `@Autowired Set<Converter>`.

Answer (score 2):

This variant works for me.
If you use java configuration, you can add your converters to existing `GenericConversionService`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

```
Config methods may have an arbitrary name and any number of arguments; each of those arguments will be autowired with a matching bean in the Spring container. Bean property setter methods are effectively just a special case of such a general config method. Such config methods do not have to be public.

    @Configuration
    class MyConfig {

    @Autowired
    void conversionService(GenericConversionService genericConversionService) {
        genericConversionService.addConverter(String.class, UUID.class, UUID::fromString);
        genericConversionService.addConverter(String.class, DateTime.class, DateTime::parse);
        genericConversionService.addConverter(String.class, EnumState.class, EnumState::valueOf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and improve your answer.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve any circular dependencies, here the steps I followed (Spring Boot v5.2.1):

Register a simple conversionService

```
@Configuration
public class ConverterProvider {

    @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService() {
        ConversionService conversionService = new GenericConversionService();
        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

Inject your custom converters

```
@Component
public class ConvertersInjection {

    @Autowired
    private GenericConversionService conversionService;

    @Autowired
    private void converters(Set<Converter> converters) {
        converters.forEach(conversionService::addConverter);
    }
}
```

The converter can even autowire your conversionService

```
@Component
public class PushNotificationConverter implements Converter<PushNotificationMessages.PushNotification, GCM> {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @Override
    public GCM convert(PushNotificationMessages.PushNotification source) {
        GCM gcm = new GCM();
        if (source.hasContent()) {
            PushNotificationMessages.PushNotification.Content content = source.getContent();
            if (content.hasData()) {
                conversionService.convert(content.getData(), gcm.getData().getClass());
            } else if (content.hasNotification()) {
                conversionService.convert(content.getNotification(), gcm.getNotification().getClass());
            }
        }
        return gcm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across a very interesting way to do this in Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12760579/204788

Using a feature called [Collection merging](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements-merging), you can essentially do this:

```
<bean id="customConversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" parent="conversionService">
    <property name="converters">
        <list merge="true">
            <bean id="StringToLoggerConverter" class="com.citi.spring.converter.LoggerConverter" />
       </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work anymore : org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'converters' of bean class [org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService]: Bean property 'converters' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to override the ConversionServiceFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet() and set the ConversionService object to your converters there.
Let your converters implement some interface that allows to set a ConversionService object, say ConversionServiceAware.
The only problem is to get access to the registered converters, so you'll also have to override the 'setConverters()' method.

```
public class MyFormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    private Set<?> cachedConverters = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void setConverters(Set<?> converters) {
        super.setConverters(converters);
        this.cachedConverters = new LinkedHashSet<>(converters);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        FormattingConversionService conversionService = getObject();
        for (Object converter : cachedConverters) {
            if (converter instanceof ConversionServiceAware) {
                ((ConversionServiceAware) converter).setConversionService(conversionService);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write a custom conversionService

```
public class CustomerConversionServiceFactoryBean extends ConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    List<Converter<Object, Object>> converters = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomerConversionServiceFactoryBean() {
        super();

    DefaultConversionService conversionservice = (DefaultConversionService)  super.getObject();

        for(int i=0;i<converters.size();i++){
            conversionservice.addConverter(converters.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

then change your xml

```
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="CustomerConversionServiceFactoryBean" >
    <property name="converters" >
        <list>
            <bean class="CustomConverter"  />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I think this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

My very very old code had the converters added in this class. To fix my issue I had to add one more converter just by adding extra lines in the same class's `addFormatters` (overridden) method. `WebMvcContext implements WebMvcConfigurer`

Lines:

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
.....
registry.addConverter( SourceType.class, TargetType.class, converter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to post this answer as an explanation of what @nikkatsa probably did to solve their own issue, since they only linked to the documentation and provided no code. Although the documentation gives all the info you need, it can be somewhat hard to translate some things to code when no explicit examples are provided.

So, @nikkatsa said they implemented and registered a custom `PropertyEditor`.
Here's an example of how to implement such a class ([the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/beans-beans.html#beans-beans-conversion) do give an explicit example for this):

```
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;

public class MyCustomClassEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (text == null)
            setValue(null);
        else {
            // do whatever conversion you need here...
            setValue(new MyCustomClass(/* args for your class */));
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        MyCustomClass currentValue = getValue();
        // convert the value back to string.
        // you don't need to override this method if you're just trying
        // to bind configuration properties, I think.
        return /* the string value */;
    }
}
```

Now, you need to register this property editor. The docs say that it will be found automatically if it's in the same package as the class it was made for and its class name is `<name of that class>Editor` (like in my example, the class being "MyCustomClass" and the editor being "MyCustomClassEditor").
If this doesn't apply to your case, here are a couple of ways to register it manually.

First way: directly with a `CustomEditorConfigurer` defined as a @Bean in a configuration class.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer() {
        
        CustomEditorConfigurer cec = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
        
        cec.setCustomEditors(Map.of(MyCustomClass.class, MyCustomClassEditor.class));
        
        return cec;
    }
}
```

This could easily be enough for you, but the documentation also talks about the `PropertyEditorRegistrar` interface, stating that

> This is particularly useful when you need to use the same set of property editors in several situations. You can write a corresponding registrar and reuse it in each case.

If you want to use a `PropertyEditorRegistrar` to register the editor, do this instead of the above:

```
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar;
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer() {
        
        CustomEditorConfigurer cec = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
        
        cec.setPropertyEditorRegistrars(new PropertyEditorRegistrar[] {new MyPropertyEditorRegistrar()});
        
        return cec;
    }
    
    public static class MyPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

        public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {

            registry.registerCustomEditor(MyCustomClass.class, new MyCustomClassEditor());
        }
    }
}
```

(The class doesn't have to be nested and static of course, you can put it in its own file if you prefer)