# Collect multiple query params in a class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am implementing a web service using spring boot 1.3.6. In my controller, I have a method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)    
createEmployee(@PathVariable String id, 
               @QueryParam(required = false, value = "department") Set<String> departments)
```

I want to collect the request parameters in a class like:

```
class EmployeeParams {
    public String id;
    public Set<String> departments;
}
```

I tried using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)    
createEmployee(EmployeeParams param) { ... }
```

But it does not work. I get the id in above class but not departments. What is the proper way of collecting the request parameters in Spring requests?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a custom converter that implements Spring *org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<String, EmployeeParams>* and register it with Spring.

See [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Spring-config). 
[This stack overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779329/spring-conversionservice-adding-converters) also discusses some details on adding a custom converter or formatter.